# Pre-populating Hibernate L1 cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, servlets

I'm using Hibernate with its L1 (Session) cache only. I was wondering whether it could be possible to pre-populate it.

Suppose I have an `Item` table, where each item has its own `id`, and I need to issue queries like "`from Item where id = :id`": if I could pre-load all the items at once I could have quicker response time (I'm using Hibernate from a Servlet under Tomcat).

Comment: The session cache is a very short-lived cache, whose lifetime is typically the lifetime of a single transaction: some milliseconds, and which is not shared between several concurrent threads. If you need to get nearly all your Items by ID in a transaction, then yes, you can pre-load all the items. Otherwise, I don't see the point.

Comment: Reading this article (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingHibernateWithTomcat), I had understood that one should leave a session open for the whole lifecycle of a servlet, that could last much more than a few seconds...

Comment: I can't access this article, but here's what the official hibernate documentation says about Session: *A single-threaded, short-lived object representing a conversation between the application and the persistent store. Wraps a JDBC java.sql.Connection.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. You'll execute your select once (without where condition and without using the resulting list), and then the data are in the session's first level cache until you clear the session or throw it away.

But in that case you have no control if the session itself throws away the pre-loaded data from its cache (this is not a functional problem, only a performance problem, and I have the feeling the hibernate version which I'm using never does so). If you want to have full control, you store the preloaded data in a static variable (a List or Map instance) and write a service which reads from this static variable instead from the database. By the way, in your environment the access to this static variable must be synchronised.

Comment: This is a very dangerous thing to do, since you could return stale data. If you want to cache Items for several sessions/transactions, you'd better use the Hibernate second-level cache: it would be transparent, and would be updated when an Item is modified. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: If it is cached for read only, it is not dangerous (pay attention with lazy loading, i. e. load all or do not close the session). Modifications after closing the session are not possible, concurrent modifications by different threads neither (all belong to the same session, and the hibernate session is not thread-safe). But all this is implied by the question, which was for the L1 cache.

Comment: I was referring to your advice of storing the pre-loaded data in a static List or Map. You'd better use the L2 chache instead of implementing your own.